# Site about Physics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm interested in Physics and game development.

At the bottom of this page, I can see a [`math`](https://math.stackexchange.com/), a [`game development`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) and the famous usual long time addicted [`stackoverflow`](http://stackoverflow.com) sites.

Is there any plan to have a site about physics problems and formulas, or should I try the `game development` one which is probably full of coders who may not have the necessary physics background?

Comment: I'd be tempted to ask on the Game Development site, as physics in games is only an approximation (albeit a good one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the link named [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

It's where new sites are proposed and defined; where they collect their seed users; and where the sites live in beta.

Visit it, love it, live it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about actual equations, the Physics proposal is currently [in beta](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). I would assume that asking how to model a particular situation would be non-specific to game development enough to be on-topic there, though I haven't really had a chance to look at what kind of material is acceptable on that site yet.

Comment: They are still thrashing out the limits. Some folks are pushing to keep it at a fairly mathy level: tending towards students and professionals.